# Giving the shape as output using GA

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

The scenario is, I want to get the output as a shape, when the number of edges, vertices and the interior angle is given as input. And am trying to do this using Genetic Algorithms.

My problem is, am having a starting trouble. How would I create the initial population randomly for this case? And how could I define the chromosomes in bitwise representation?

I was referring some PPTs. 
[image]

[image]

But in my case, I think I can't represent the chromosome as bits. Because it's numeric value that I would be giving isn't it? Any clues to make me move forward?

Answer (score 0):

Genetic Algorithms don't have to be represented as bits, although I prefer to do it this way. The best way is probably to just convert the numbers from binary to whatever form you need to represent your shapes and back again.

You can either scale the binary or clip the edges to make it fit whatever boundary you need.

In terms of initialisation all you need to do is work out how many bits you need to represent all your input and generate this randomly. For example, if you wanted 3 whole numbers between 0-255 you would need 24 bits (8 * 3). Just randomly generate this number for each chromosome in the population. When creating the shape you just split the chromosome into 3, convert into your 3 whole numbers and use them.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try